# Calculate curvature from a smoothed spline fit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, smoothing

I'm fitting a smoothed spline to an (x,y) closed outline of a shape and I want to find the local curvature of the shape. The curvature I get is very noisy and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it.

```
% Calculate the arc length along the shape
s = cumsum(sqrt([0,diff(x)].^2 + [0 diff(y)].^2));

% Overlap when fitting to get end gradient correct
s_fit = [s-max(s); s; s+max(s)];
x_fit = [x x x]; y_fit = [y y y];

% Find parametric spline fit
fx = fit(s_fit,x_fit','smoothingspline','SmoothingParam',0.1);
fy = fit(s_fit,y_fit','smoothingspline','SmoothingParam',0.1);

% Differentiate fit at discrete points
ds = linspace(0,max(s),1000);
[dx_ds,ddx_ds] = differentiate(fx,ds);
[dy_ds,ddy_ds] = differentiate(fy,ds);

% Calculate signed curvature
curvature = (dx_ds.*ddy_ds - dy_ds.*ddx_ds)./(dx_ds.^2+dy_ds.^2).^(3/2);
```

The resulting calculated curvature is approximately correct, but rather messy. I need the smoothing spline as the outline I start with (x,y) is pixelated.